# What is the level bonus for after making a creation?

Tags: geneforge-2

Each time you shape a creation, you get the following text:

```
Make creation : Fyora successfully created!
 Level bonus for shaper skill : +4.
 Level bonus for knowledge of ability : +4.
```

What does this level bonus mean ?

(The tag only says Geneforge-2 but it applies for all games in the series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your creations level up with you, and as they do so they also gain health, stats, and spell energy. From a bit of testing in the Geneforge 2 tutorial stages, it seems like every creature has a base level, which is then increased by your skill in shaping that creature, and further increased by your skill in the relevant shaping sub-skill.

For the Fyora, for example, its base level is 1. That then increases by 1 for each point you've invested in fire shaping, and further increases if you buy training in the Create Fyora skill from a trainer, though I'm not sure by how much.

For the Artila, its base level is 3, which is then increased based off your magic shaping level and Create Artila training. I'd imagine similar rules exist for all the possible creations, but I've not got a comprehensive list of base levels.

If you level up your shaping skills after creating something, your creations do not gain any levels, but creations gain experience and level up with you. This means you can still get stronger creations without investing in shaping skills, but you need to be far more patient

In your case, your character seems to have 4 points invested in fire shaping, and I suspect has bought the create fyora skill 3 times, totalling 4 points from the fact that it's a starting skill, but I'd be interested in knowing for certain. This seems to mean that you can cheese the shaping rules by equipping some items that increase your shaping skill in a friendly town, shaping your creations, then swapping over to some tankier gear to fight.

Comment: You're right, Fire shaping was 4 and Create Fyora was 4.

Comment: So it does seem to be that your new creation's level = base level (shown in creation screen) + points invested in relevant shaping area for that creation (fire/battle/magic) + points obtained in the ability section for `Create X`.